# row.names are not duplicated, but read.table fails with duplication error message

Tags: r, read.table

I have the following file (shortened)

```
GeneSymbol  ENSG00000000003 ENSG00000000003
GSM1100843_032310_270628991_005.2.CEL    3.914867    3.408872
GSM1100843_032310_270628991_005.CEL  3.914867    3.408872    
GSM1100844_032310_270629051_016.CEL  3.880304    3.036225    
GSM1100845_032310_270629071_019.CEL  3.530294    3.040007    
GSM1100846_032310_270629091_009.CEL  3.929253    4.078683    
GSM1100847_032310_296438041_008.CEL  4.025423    3.246378    
GSM1100848_032310_BDP008_049.CEL     3.786376    3.079892    
GSM1100849_032310_BDP020_051.CEL     3.536456    3.063119    
GSM1100850_032310_BDP022_052.CEL     3.357809    2.985093    
GSM1100851_032310_BDP039_053.CEL     3.806282    3.414897
```

and try to read it with

```
theDataFrame = read.table(fileName, header = TRUE,sep="\t",row.names=1)
```

, but get

```
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

? Why? Row.names would be the `*.CEL` entries, no?

Comment: I don't know anything about R, but the documentation suggests that either you need to format your file differently or provide a vector of *all* the row labels: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

Comment: Don't specify `sep="\t"`. Though it could be the cases that you have dupes in `GeneSymbol` in your real data. You could try reading it without specifying `row.names=1` neither and the check if there are duplicates in the first column.

Comment: The error must be the first and the second entries.. I guess it ignores all after dots `.`, that why it says they have the same name. Try renaming just to see any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your tab separator may not be correct.  Try using a whitespace separater with `sep=""`

```
theDataFrame = read.table(fileName, header = TRUE,sep="",row.names=1)
```

I was able to read your example using that.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it was a glitch in the matrix. I played around a bit more and it works now, with the unaltered files.

```
theDataFrame = read.table(fileName, header = TRUE,sep="\t",row.names = 1)
```

Thanks for your help.